# Resource File name search

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, resx

I have a single resource file right now, but it will eventually grow to more.  Each of the resource files will have a consistent pattern for the Name but the Value will be different, in most cases.  Each of the resource files (*.resx) will be closely tied to classes i am building.

With that being said, the Name patterns are as such: `Key?`, `SKey`, `UKey?`, and `SUKey`.

- `Key?`: ? could be any single character.  Regex pattern would be something like this `Key[A-Z]`
- `UKey?` : ? could be any single character. Similar to `Key?`
- `SKey` & `SUKey`: Only one of these names possible any of the Resource files

I really just want to know, what would be the best approach for extracting the values in the resource file as they will not always have every letter between A & Z?

### Edited 2012-09-20 11:48AM CST

```
ResourceManager resmgr = project.resx_name.ResourceManager;
string[] mtch = resmgr.getstring("Key?").toarray<string>();
```

Then iterate through the array and build a string from the resulting matches.  All of the specified `Key` patterns, above, will result in a string value regex pattern.

### Edited 2012-09-22 9:00AM CST

Ok here is the logic i have so far, can anyone valid its viability?  I havent finished building the other components of the class, so i am going to finish the development of them and then start testing hopefully middle to late next week.

```
ResourceSet rs = syntaxhighlighter.vbnet.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet( CultureInfo.CurrentCulture , true , true );
foreach( DictionaryEntry entry in rs ) {
    if( Regex.IsMatch( entry.Key.ToString() , "Key" ) ) {
        if( Regex.IsMatch( entry.Key.ToString() , "^Key[A-Z]" ) ) {
            this._keys += entry.Value.ToString();
        } else if( Regex.IsMatch( entry.Key.ToString() , "^SKey$" ) ) {
            this._keys += entry.Value.ToString();
        } else if( Regex.IsMatch( entry.Key.ToString() , "^UKey[A-Z]" ) ) {
            this._ukeys += entry.Value.ToString();
        } else if( Regex.IsMatch( entry.Key.ToString() , "^SUKey$" ) ) {
            this._ukeys += entry.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
this._attr = @"<(.*\.)?(.+?)(Attribute)?(\((.*)?\))?>";
```

#### Resource.resx File

Name - Value

- KeyA - AddHandler|AddressOf|Alias|And|AndAlso|As
- SKey - #Const|#Else|#ElseIf|#End|#If|\=|\&|\&\=|*|*\=|/|/\=|\|\\=|\^|\^\=|+|+\=|-|-\=|>>|>>\=|\<\<|\<\<\=

Comment: Can you elaborate some more?  What do you mean "best approach for extracting the values", and why would it be different than the normal approach?  And, are you using Winforms?  WPF?  ASP.NET?

Comment: Csharp WinForms.  Most of the time in the past i have had verify specific Setting Names and so didnt have to have an Abstract way of Name checking.  I have a App-Resource that holds a generic reference to "Possible" names in the other specific Resource Files.  The Resource Files will be strictly associated with a Well-Defined Class that will load "its" Resource File upon initialization.  As stated there are 2 very specific Name entries in the Resource File that i know will exist.  Its the other Name ranges i cannot guarantee.

Comment: So how about, on initialization, scan the "possible" names using GetGlobalResource, and store an internal dictionary of the actual available names.

Comment: Problem is that i am building compilation library, at the moment its only one Resource File, but im almost finished and getting prepped for the next one.  SO i want to build a Template class that will perform these generic operations without implementing it 2 or more times.  When you say `scan` do you mean using a pattern match comparison?

Comment: no, by "scan" I just meant literally check if each name exists by trying to get it.  I'm having a hard time following what you're doing; maybe posting some code would help?

Comment: ok ill put the conceptual logic above, from other pattern match comparisons i have used in the past.  May not be exactly what im looking for but may get the point acrossed.